# Using Google Drive API without registration on Google Chrome Store

Tags: google-drive-api

Can I use Google Drive API without registration my extension on Google Chrome Store?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This has changed in the meanwhile and was true for Drive API v1.

No.
You can use the Documents List API for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Your app only needs to be registered in the API Console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Client ID for web applications in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and define callback URLs.
Basically it's about to get oAuth working in the first place... then you can really *USE* it.

Drive API has to be enabled there, under 'Services'.